# Get post and poster information during 'publish_post' in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the publish_post hook, I want access to the email address of the user posting (even just their user id will work if I can't get that) and the id of the post.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $post;
$author_id = $post->post_author;
```

Comment: Negative ghost rider, for some reason $post is not available when the publish_post hook is, well, hooked. I don't know why, I just know it's not.

Comment: You sure? 
`function tttt() {
 global $post;
 var_dump($post);}
add_action('publish_post', 'tttt');`
 This works for me.

Comment: How very strange. Can you pastebin your var_dump output for me?

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, apparently when using the p2 theme you do not get $post during an ajax post... I will mark your answer since your response would have worked otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can get the post id (with `$ID` or `$post_id`) you should avoid using `global` since referencing a global variable might give unintended consequences in the future. Do this instead:

```
add_action("publish_post", "your_function", 10, 1);
function your_function($post_id) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $author_id = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author_id );
}
```